# How to post to a Web page

Tags: c#

This is something I am curious about since I learnt how to invoke an url and get a http response so I could parse the results in my application. Something like what Chris M says here:

[Faking browser request in ASP.net C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/642860/faking-browser-request-in-asp-net-c)

Now what I am wondering is how can I post a form that I download in this way, filling in the fields of the form.

I don't really need this for my work, it's just to kill my curiosity as a programmer :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way (in C#) to simulate a form post with values:

```
using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
    NameValueCollection fields = new NameValueCollection();
    fields.Add("foo", "123");
    fields.Add("bar", "abc");
    client.UploadValues(address, fields);
}
```

Just for completeness, jQuery can do it more efficiently again...

```
$.post(address, { foo: "123", bar: "abc" } );
```

If you want to *inspect* the html to create your POST, either use [`WebBrowser`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.aspx) and automation, or use the [Html Agility Pack](http://www.codeplex.com/htmlagilitypack) to look at it.

Comment: WebBrowser and automation I will not consider because when i will try to "play" without any user interface.

client.UploadValues looks like the easy way to do what i have in mind :) thanks