# How to bypass HttpWebRequest detection?

Tags: c#, asp.net, html-agility-pack

Actually I'm playing around with the HtmlAgilityPack.

I've noticed that it can parse the HTML from the HtmlWebRequest.

I would like to know is there a way to bypass the "HttpWebRequest" detection?
It's because when I tried to use the HttpWebRequestto get the HTML content, it seems that the server knows me I am using "HttpWebRequest" and does not allow me to retrieve the HTML inside.

Here is my source code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var targetUrl = new Uri("http://www.aastocks.com/tc/ltp/rtquote.aspx?symbol=03800");
    var webReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(targetUrl);
    WebResponse webRes = webReq.GetResponse();
    System.IO.Stream stream = webRes.GetResponseStream();
    System.Text.Encoding encode = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8");
    System.IO.StreamReader reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(stream, encode);            
    HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
    doc.Load(reader);
    foreach (HtmlNode link in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//html"))
    {
        Label1.Text += link.InnerHtml;
    }
}
```

I'm not trying to do something to violate the copyright, but just curious about this.

Comment: Your question is not clear. What you mean by "HttpWebRequest detection"? What detection? Do you get any error?

Comment: I'm sorry that I'm a newbie .NET developer, therefore I may not give a correct description. The situation is like this, I can access the link with my browser. However, if I use the "HttpWebRequest", it seems that the server knows me that I'm not using a browser to initiate a request. That's my question. Sorry for misleading.

Comment: For this see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/642860/faking-browser-request-in-asp-net-c) the accepted give proper code `((System.Net.HttpWebRequest)objRequest).UserAgent = 
   "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.0)";`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no such thing as HttpWebRequest detection.

However, the page you are accessing may be not as simple: it may be loaded by several HTTP requests (iframes), or via AJAX, or require certain HTTP headers in the request.

The best thing I can advise: track the HTTP traffic between your browser and the website (for example, with [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/)). Then track the traffic between your application (which sends the request programmatically) and the same website.

Spot the difference, and make your application behave exactly like the browser does.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Shadow Wizard, the programme works now.

The solution is setting the UserAgent after webReq.Create(targetUrl).

```
webReq.UserAgent = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.0)";
```

Comment: Of course you should realize that this is not the universal solution for such problems :)