# Not returning 1/5 cookies, C# short and sweet code: RichTextBox, Form1_Load, using System.Net / System.Collections.Specialized

Tags: c#, .net, http, cookies

```
 private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       string site = "https://signin.ebay.com/ws/eBayISAPI.dll?co_partnerId=2&siteid=0&UsingSSL=1&MfcISAPICommand=SignInWelcome&userid=USERNAME&pass=PWD&sngBt=Sign%20in";
       CookieContainer cookieJar = new CookieContainer();

       HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(site);
       request.CookieContainer = cookieJar;

       HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
       System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());

       richTextBox1.Text = sr.ReadToEnd();
       foreach (Cookie c1 in response.Cookies)
       {
           richTextBox1.AppendText(c1.Name.ToString() + "\n\n");
       }
   }
```

I've been messing around with Fiddler and the headers for 2 days with nothing better.  Please help me retrieve this last cookie.  In the browser the URL will log you right in (Change USERNAME and PWD respectively), and returns ds2, ebay, dp1, cssg, nonsession cookies.. the code is missing the ebay cookie.

Request Headers:

Client

Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8

Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3

Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch

Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8

User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.17 (KHTML, like Gecko)

Chrome/24.0.1312.56 Safari/537.17

Transport

Connection: keep-alive

Host: signin.ebay.com

```
 private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       string site = "https://signin.ebay.com/ws/eBayISAPI.dll?co_partnerId=2&siteid=0&UsingSSL=1&MfcISAPICommand=SignInWelcome&userid=USERNAME&pass=PWD&sngBt=Sign%20in";
       CookieContainer cookieJar = new CookieContainer();

        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(site);
        request.Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8";
        request.Headers.Add("Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3");
        request.Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch");
        request.Headers.Add("Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8");
        request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/24.0.1312.56 Safari/537.17";

        request.CookieContainer = cookieJar;

       HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
       System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());

       richTextBox1.Text = sr.ReadToEnd();
       foreach (Cookie c1 in response.Cookies)
       {
           richTextBox1.AppendText(c1.Name.ToString() + "\n\n");
       }
   }
```

Fiddler will take me no further?  this returns no source, but does return the ebay cookie..

Comment: I've seen similar issues.  Try setting the user agent on the web request to a common browser's agent.  I've had this work on other sites.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/642860/faking-browser-request-in-asp-net-c-sharp

Comment: nope, not the user-agent: tried those two + the fiddler result: User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/24.0.1312.56 Safari/537.17

Comment: eBay login is little more complicated!

Comment: Your web browser settings are blocking cookies. <-- is sent as response!

Comment: which cookie you are missing?

Comment: Do the _response_ headers contain the cookie you are looking for (when not using the browser, but your code via fiddler)? Seems like the best place to look first.

Comment: AppDeveloper: what?!?  why in the hell would the response be that?

Comment: what do you mean by more complicated though?

Comment: None of the cookies are in the REQUEST headers when sniffing the app.. you can see them in the Response though...
Sniffing the browser login, there are cookies in the request side + more cookies.

Comment: npii, nonsession, lucky9, cid, dp1 are the only cookie that i can see

Comment: cid, cssg, dp1, ds1, ebay, JSESSIONID, lucky9, nonsession, npii, ns1, oam.Flash.RENDERMAP.TOKEN, s, secses, shs

Comment: you seem to be holding something back AppDeveloper:"eBay login is little more complicated! – AppDeveloper 1 hour ago" ?!?

Comment: Your web browser settings are blocking cookies. <-- is sent as response! – AppDeveloper 2 hours ago... that something in 'request' that needs to be changed? -- i tried request.SupportsCookieContainer..true, no go still

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14526966/922198

Comment: @user209214 - sorry for the last response, i got a little busy!

Comment: @user209214 Cookies on the request side when using a browser is because the browser had previously connected with that site and remembered them. Your request doesn't send cookies because you don't tell it to.

Answer (score 1):

Well finally,

```
class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CookieContainer cookieJar = new CookieContainer();
        HTTP http = new HTTP(cookieJar);
        string user = "this is not my username";
        string pass = "this is not my password";

        //some cookies are set before login & they are needed for an user to login, for that reason only you were getting the error
        string responseData = http.DownloadString("https://signin.ebay.com/ws/eBayISAPI.dll?SignIn");

        string midParamValue = ParseMid(responseData, "name=\"mid\" id=\"mid\" value=\"", "\"");
        string bUrlPrfx = ParseMid(responseData, "id=\"bUrlPrfx\" value=\"", "\"");
        string rqid = ParseMid(responseData, "id=\"bUrlPrfx\" value=\"", "\"");
        string pdata =
            string.Format(
                "MfcISAPICommand=SignInWelcome&bhid=a1%253Dna%7Ea2%253Dna%7Ea3%253Dna%7Ea4%253DMozilla%7Ea5%253DNetscape%7Ea6%253D5.0%2520%28Windows%29%7Ea7%253D20100101%7Ea8%253Dna%7Ea9%253Dtrue%7Ea10%253DWindows%2520NT%25206.1%253B%2520WOW64%7Ea11%253Dtrue%7Ea12%253DWin32%7Ea13%253Dna%7Ea14%253DMozilla%252F5.0%2520%28Windows%2520NT%25206.1%253B%2520WOW64%253B%2520rv%253A18.0%29%2520Gecko%252F20100101%2520Firefox%252F18.0%7Ea15%253Dfalse%7Ea16%253Den-US%7Ea17%253Dna%7Ea18%253Dsignin.ebay.com%7Ea19%253Dna%7Ea20%253Dna%7Ea21%253Dna%7Ea22%253Dna%7Ea23%253D1366%7Ea24%253D768%7Ea25%253D24%7Ea26%253D738%7Ea27%253Dna%7Ea28%253DFri%2520Jan%252025%25202013%252022%253A20%253A09%2520GMT%252B0530%2520%28India%2520Standard%2520Time%29%7Ea29%253D5.5%7Ea30%253Dpdf%257Cpdf%257Cpdf%257C%7Ea31%253Dyes%7Ea32%253Dna%7Ea33%253Dna%7Ea34%253Dno%7Ea35%253Dno%7Ea36%253Dyes%7Ea37%253Dno%7Ea38%253Donline%7Ea39%253Dno%7Ea40%253DWindows%2520NT%25206.1%253B%2520WOW64%7Ea41%253Dno%7Ea42%253Dno%7Ea43%253D&UsingSSL=1&inputversion=2&lse=true&lsv=11.5.502&mid=AQAAAThpCRHvAAUxMzg5OTM0YzA2MS5hNWFiODMyLjJmNDcyLmZmZTlhOWUwEZMPFiRFo7yUjykHfCAFgp%2Bk9%2Bk*&kgver=1&kgupg=1&kgstate=r&omid=&hmid=&rhr=f&siteid=0&co_partnerId=2&ru=&pp=&pa1=&pa2=&pa3=&i1=-1&pageType=-1&rtmData=&bUrlPrfx={0}&rqid={1}&kgct=&userid={2}&pass={3}&keepMeSignInOption=1&sgnBt=Sign+in&htmid={4}&kdata=%251E%251F%2510%251E1359132609409%251E1%251F%2510%251E1359132609409%251E0%251F%2510%251E1359132609410%251E1%251F%2510%251E1359132609410%251E0%251F%251B%251E1359132612808%251E1%251F%2510%251E1359132612837%251E1%251F%2510%251E1359132612838%251E0%251F%251B%251E1359132612977%251E0%251F", bUrlPrfx, rqid, user,pass, midParamValue);
        responseData =
            http.UploadString("https://signin.ebay.com/ws/eBayISAPI.dll?co_partnerId=2&siteid=0&UsingSSL=1", pdata);


        PrintAllCookies(cookieJar);
        Console.Read();

    }

    private static void PrintAllCookies(CookieContainer cookies)
    {
        Hashtable table = (Hashtable)cookies.GetType().InvokeMember("m_domainTable",
                                                                     BindingFlags.NonPublic |
                                                                     BindingFlags.GetField |
                                                                     BindingFlags.Instance,
                                                                     null,
                                                                     cookies,
                                                                     new object[] { });



        foreach (string key in table.Keys)
        {
            foreach (Cookie cookie in cookies.GetCookies(new Uri(string.Format("http://{0}/", key.StartsWith(".", StringComparison.Ordinal) ? "www" + key : key))))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Name = {0} ; Value = {1} ; Domain = {2}", cookie.Name, cookie.Value,
                                  cookie.Domain);
            }
        }
    }

    public static string ParseMid(string text, string firstString, string lastString)
    {

        string str = text;
        int pos1 = str.IndexOf(firstString, StringComparison.Ordinal) + firstString.Length;
        int pos2 = str.IndexOf(lastString, pos1 + 1, StringComparison.Ordinal);
        string finalString = str.Substring(pos1, pos2 - pos1);
        return finalString;
    } 
}
```

You will need a class that i used, its a simple WebClient that supports CookieContainer

The output :

[image: The output of all cookies]

> Have printed cookie value to "none" as i logged in with my username :P

---

HTTP.cs

```
public class HTTP : WebClient
{
    public HTTP()
        : this(new CookieContainer())
    { }

    public HTTP(CookieContainer c)
    {
        CookieContainer = c;
    }
    public CookieContainer CookieContainer { get; set; }

    protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri address)
    {
        WebRequest request = base.GetWebRequest(address);

        var castRequest = request as HttpWebRequest;
        if (castRequest != null)
        {
            castRequest.CookieContainer = CookieContainer;
            castRequest.ServicePoint.Expect100Continue = false;
            castRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        }

        return request;
    }

}
```

Comment: close but no cigar..
shs, lucky9, npii, JSESSIONID, oam.Flash.RENDERMAP.TOKEN are still not in the request side.

Comment: @user209214 - the login seems working fine! atleast for me, iam logged in to ebay with that many cookies in my container

Comment: it shows 8 cookies in the container i believe.. they keep adding up: missing shs, lucky9, npii, JSESSIONID, oam.Flash.RENDERMAP.TOKEN on the request side.. i might need a quick rundown on what you did to come to the code so far also if you have time/care.  thanks, much appreciated.

Comment: What puts them on the request side?

Comment: what delegates them to the request side in a sniffer that is, since things seem to not always be the same

Comment: ('ebay', 'js', 1) are the errors, it seems at least the shs, jsession and npii come from another link, i haven't found lucky9 or oam.Flash.RENDERMAP.TOKEN

Comment: anyone get any further on this? i'm clueless, i've been trying to decipher in my freetime, but gotten almost nowhere since lucky9 is not anywhere in the source, nor are the other missing ones.

Comment: Is someone able to guide me through the process so i don't need help with something like this again?  Much appreciated.  I have wireshark + Fiddler.

Answer (score 0):

namespace watcher
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CookieContainer cookieJar = new CookieContainer();
        HTTP http = new HTTP(cookieJar);
        string user = "id";
        string pass = "password";

        //some cookies are set before login & they are needed for an user to login, for that reason only you were getting the error
        string responseData = http.DownloadString("https://signin.ebay.com/ws/eBayISAPI.dll?SignIn");

        string midParamValue = ParseMid(responseData, "name=\"mid\" id=\"mid\" value=\"", "\"");
        string bUrlPrfx = ParseMid(responseData, "id=\"bUrlPrfx\" value=\"", "\"");
        string rqid = ParseMid(responseData, "id=\"bUrlPrfx\" value=\"", "\"");
        string hidUrl = ParseMid(responseData, "name=\"hidUrl\" value=\"", "\""); //"name=\"hidUrl\" value="http://my.ebay.com/ws/eBayISAPI.dll?MyeBay"
        //string lucky9 = ParseMid(responseData, 
        string pdata =
            string.Format(
                "MfcISAPICommand=SignInWelcome&bhid=a1%253Dna%7Ea2%253Dna%7Ea3%253Dna%7Ea4%253DMozilla%7Ea5%253DNetscape%7Ea6%253D5.0%2520%28Windows%29%7Ea7%253D20100101%7Ea8%253Dna%7Ea9%253Dtrue%7Ea10%253DWindows%2520NT%25206.1%253B%2520WOW64%7Ea11%253Dtrue%7Ea12%253DWin32%7Ea13%253Dna%7Ea14%253DMozilla%252F5.0%2520%28Windows%2520NT%25206.1%253B%2520WOW64%253B%2520rv%253A18.0%29%2520Gecko%252F20100101%2520Firefox%252F18.0%7Ea15%253Dfalse%7Ea16%253Den-US%7Ea17%253Dna%7Ea18%253Dsignin.ebay.com%7Ea19%253Dna%7Ea20%253Dna%7Ea21%253Dna%7Ea22%253Dna%7Ea23%253D1366%7Ea24%253D768%7Ea25%253D24%7Ea26%253D738%7Ea27%253Dna%7Ea28%253DFri%2520Jan%252025%25202013%252022%253A20%253A09%2520GMT%252B0530%2520%28India%2520Standard%2520Time%29%7Ea29%253D5.5%7Ea30%253Dpdf%257Cpdf%257Cpdf%257C%7Ea31%253Dyes%7Ea32%253Dna%7Ea33%253Dna%7Ea34%253Dno%7Ea35%253Dno%7Ea36%253Dyes%7Ea37%253Dno%7Ea38%253Donline%7Ea39%253Dno%7Ea40%253DWindows%2520NT%25206.1%253B%2520WOW64%7Ea41%253Dno%7Ea42%253Dno%7Ea43%253D&UsingSSL=1&inputversion=2&lse=true&lsv=11.5.502&mid=AQAAAThpCRHvAAUxMzg5OTM0YzA2MS5hNWFiODMyLjJmNDcyLmZmZTlhOWUwEZMPFiRFo7yUjykHfCAFgp%2Bk9%2Bk*&kgver=1&kgupg=1&kgstate=r&omid=&hmid=&rhr=f&siteid=0&co_partnerId=2&ru=&pp=&pa1=&pa2=&pa3=&i1=-1&pageType=-1&rtmData=&bUrlPrfx={0}&rqid={1}&kgct=&userid={2}&pass={3}&keepMeSignInOption=1&sgnBt=Sign+in&htmid={4}&kdata=%251E%251F%2510%251E1359132609409%251E1%251F%2510%251E1359132609409%251E0%251F%2510%251E1359132609410%251E1%251F%2510%251E1359132609410%251E0%251F%251B%251E1359132612808%251E1%251F%2510%251E1359132612837%251E1%251F%2510%251E1359132612838%251E0%251F%251B%251E1359132612977%251E0%251F", bUrlPrfx, rqid, user, pass, midParamValue);
        responseData =
            http.UploadString("https://signin.ebay.com/ws/eBayISAPI.dll?co_partnerId=2&siteid=0&UsingSSL=1", pdata);
        richTextBox1.Text = responseData;

        PrintAllCookies(cookieJar);
    }
    private void PrintAllCookies(CookieContainer cookies)
    {
        Hashtable table = (Hashtable)cookies.GetType().InvokeMember("m_domainTable",
                                                                     BindingFlags.NonPublic |
                                                                     BindingFlags.GetField |
                                                                     BindingFlags.Instance,
                                                                     null,
                                                                     cookies,
                                                                     new object[] { });

        foreach (string key in table.Keys)
        {
            foreach (Cookie cookie in cookies.GetCookies(new Uri(string.Format("http://{0}/", key.StartsWith(".", StringComparison.Ordinal) ? "www" + key : key))))
            {
                richTextBox1.AppendText("Name = " + cookie.Name.ToString() + " Value = " + cookie.Value.ToString() + "Domain = " + cookie.Domain.ToString() + "\n\n");
            }
        }
    }

    public string ParseMid(string text, string firstString, string lastString)
    {

        string str = text;
        int pos1 = str.IndexOf(firstString, StringComparison.Ordinal) + firstString.Length;
        int pos2 = str.IndexOf(lastString, pos1 + 1, StringComparison.Ordinal);
        string finalString = str.Substring(pos1, pos2 - pos1);
        return finalString;
    }
    public class HTTP : WebClient
    {
        public HTTP()
            : this(new CookieContainer())
        { }

        public HTTP(CookieContainer c)
        {
            CookieContainer = c;
        }
        public CookieContainer CookieContainer { get; set; }

        protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri address)
        {
            WebRequest request = base.GetWebRequest(address);

            var castRequest = request as HttpWebRequest;
            if (castRequest != null)
            {
                castRequest.CookieContainer = CookieContainer;
                castRequest.ServicePoint.Expect100Continue = false;
                castRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
                //castRequest.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
                castRequest.Headers.Add("Cache-Control", "max-age=0");
                castRequest.Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8";
                castRequest.Headers.Add("Accept-Charset", "ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3");
                //castRequest.Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip,deflate,sdch");
                castRequest.Headers.Add("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.8");
                castRequest.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/24.0.1312.57 Safari/537.17";

                castRequest.Headers.Add("Origin", "https://signin.ebay.com");
                castRequest.Referer = "https://signin.ebay.com/ws/eBayISAPI.dll?SignIn";
                castRequest.KeepAlive = true;
                castRequest.Host = "signin.ebay.com";
            }

            return request;
        }
    }
}
}
```

i added some more headers, the packet looks similar to a normal login packet, but still erroring at either lucky9 or a url redirect?  I'm not sure about troubleshooting this further.. i've attempted to modify the url with the &ru=http%3A%2F%2Fmy.ebay.com%2Fws%2FeBayISAPI.dll%3FMyEbayBeta%26MyeBay%3D%26guest%3D1&pageType=3984 header, but it accomplished nothing.  Someone else will have to help with the final step.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://secureir.ebaystatic.com/v4js/z/i5/r32gctn0fu3vjkpge2mjhij3q.js#SYS-ZAM_vjo_e809_1_Ear_en_US"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">vjo.dsf.error.ErrorHandlerManager.register(new vjo.dsf.error.DefaultErrorHandler());
vjo.dsf.error.ErrorHandlerManager.enableOnError(true, false);
vjo.dsf.cookie.VjCookieJar.sCookieDomain = '.ebay.com';vjo.dsf.cookie.VjCookieJar.writeCookielet('ebay','js','1');
</script>
<script language="JavaScript">window.location="http://my.ebay.com/ws/eBayISAPI.dll?MyEbayBeta&MyeBay=&guest=1"</script>
<div class="pagewidth">
    <div class="pageminwidth">
        <div class="pagelayout">
            <div class="pagecontainer">
                <div class="GlobalNavigation" id="GlobalNavigation"><div><script type="text/javascript">var _GlobalNavHeaderUtf8Encoding=true,includeHost='https://secureinclude.ebaystatic.com/';</script>

                <div class="CentralArea" id="CentralArea"><div>      <form name="AlertSuppressor" method="post"><input type="hidden" name="hidUrl" value="http://my.ebay.com/ws/eBayISAPI.dll?MyEbayBeta&amp;MyeBay=&amp;guest=1"></form>      <noscript><meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="0; url = http://my.ebay.com/ws/eBayISAPI.dll?MyEbayBeta&amp;MyeBay=&amp;guest=1"></noscript>
<b>If you are seeing this page, your browser settings prevent you from automatically redirecting to a new URL.</b></td></tr></table>
<div class="buttonDiv_space"><a href="http://my.ebay.com/ws/eBayISAPI.dll?MyEbayBeta&amp;MyeBay=&amp;guest=1">Continue</a>
<div class="SupportiveNavigation" id="SupportiveNavigation">
<script type="text/javascript">vjo.dsf.cookie.VjCookieJar.writeCookieEx("lucky9", "8067469", 730);
</script>
```

Name = ebay Value = ###

Name = dp1 Value = ###

Name = cssg Value = ###

Name = s Value = ###

Name = nonsession Value = ###

Name = cid Value = ###

Name = ds1 Value = ###

Name = ns1 Value = ###

Name = secses Value = ###

Name = shs Value = ###